# BigQuery Record Type Missing

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery Web UI earlier used to display `RECORD` type in the dropdown but it has disappeared.

[image]

Can anyone tell me where did that option go & how to add a new col existing table that has TYPE record? the old trick of `bq show` & `bq update` Fails with following error message:

> BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table circular-gist-812:analytics_demo.user_notifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose source format as CSV - you do not have record option
Choose JSON and you will get it